# JQuery найти элементы с определенным классом и id

Tags: jquery, search, атрибуты, find

Например

```
<td class="table-status" id="1">
....
</td>
<td class="table-status" id="2">
....
</td>
```

и как мне достать td с id 2 и заменить внутри содержимое(дочерние элементы)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var el2 = $("#2");
console.log(el2[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td class="table-status" id="1">
      ....
    </td>
    <td class="table-status" id="2">
      ....
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

> а если надо заменить дочерние элементы, то как?

Вы уже попробовали использовать вот это?

https://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: а если надо заменить дочерние элементы, то как?

Comment: @Лукас Я не понимаю. Я ответил на Ваш вопрос, который написан в вопросе? Знак "галочка" - слева.

Comment: я дополнил вопрос

Comment: Чтобы выбрать дочерние используйте [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)